# amazon aws sns, sms option not available?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

I'm trying to use the amazon AWS to send a text message to my phone. 
In particular, I'm using the SNS service and got stuck in the process of creating a new subscription.

In the online tutorial they see this:
[image: SMS available in the drop-down menu]

How come I see this?
[image: SMS not available in the drop-down menu]

Sorry my screenshot won't work while in the drop-down menu, so I took a ghetto picture with my phone.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

never mind... apparently SMS only works on us-east region, you need to change the region from the sns management page. All seem normal now.

Comment: Update: They now support 6 regions and 200 countries. Link in my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

For other people that have this problem http://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/ -> SMS Related Questions section. It was very helpful for me.

"Q: Does Amazon SNS currently support notification delivery to international phone numbers?
Currently Amazon SNS will only accept US phone numbers as valid subscription end-points."

Answer (score 2):

Update:
SMS now works from 6 regions and SMS messages can be sent to some 200 countries.

These regions will work.

US East (N. Virginia)
US West (Oregon)
EU (Ireland)
Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
Asia Pacific (Singapore)
Asia Pacific (Sydney)

The complete list of supported countries and regions is available here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html